# Как скоприлировать проект, чтобы у пользователя не требовало VCRUNTIME140.dll?

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

Есть проект, который разрабатываю в Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 на чистом С (ещё в настройках линковщика поставила, что код С, а не C++) с использованием WinAPI. Компилирую как Release x64. Запускаю на Windows 7 Professional x64, где нету Visual Studio (то есть не установлены VCRUNTIME140.dll и т.д.). При запуске данного приложения почему-то выдаёт ошибку `The program can't start because vcruntime140.dll is missing`. Мне кажется, что это ненормально и что-то не так с компиляцией, ибо эта библиотека нужна для отладки, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Это не библиотека для отладки, она экпортирует функции, например `memchr/memcmp/memcpy/memmove/memset` и другие. Если вы их используете, то получите ошибку.

Comment: @Zergatul можно чем-то заменить эти функции, чтобы не требовало какую-то "нестандартную" библиотеку? Просто чтобы любой рядовой пользователь мог запустить моё приложение без ошибок?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте опцию /MT (статическое использование библиотеки времени выполнения) для указания типа линковки рунтаймовских библиотек. В результате весь используемый код библиотек будет помещен в исполняемый файл.
Подробнее можно посмотреть [/MD, /MT, /LD (использование библиотеки времени выполнения)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) и [Особенности библиотеки CRT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/abx4dbyh.aspx).

Comment: У меня в `Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library` уже стоит значение `Multi-threaded (/MT)`. Видимо, дело не в этом.

Comment: @J.Huxley странно... Вы полностью перестроили проект? Все файлы перекомпилированы заново с этим ключом? Нет ли какой-то сторонней библиотеки?

Comment: @Harry для перекомриляции всех файлов нужно сделать Clean и Rebuild Project, или этого недостаточно?

Comment: Да вроде достаточно..

Answer (score 0):

На этот счёт имеется общая рекомендация: если приложению необходима какая-то библиотека, то включите её в установщик приложения. Это наиболее простой и надёжный путь.
Либо включите требование дополнительной установки (возможно, автоматической) пакета распространения этой библиотеки

Comment: А можно обойтись без развёртвания? Я вот попыталась статически прилинковать библиотеку, но видимо установить `Runtime Library` в `Multi-threaded` мало. Или что-то мешает этому? Но, думаю, в данном случае была бы ошибка линковки.

Comment: Лично у меня полноценно работающие приложения получались через процедуру развёртывания/установки. По другому то же пытался, но не получалось, может что-то неправильно делал?