# Почему исполняемый файл требует api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll?

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

Разрабатывала на чистом С (WinAPI) два разных приложения. Компилировала как релиз с статическим использованием библиотеки времени выполнения. Отдельно оба запускались на тестовой ОС (Windows 7 Professional), где был базовый набор dll. Объеденила исходники в один проект, компилирую так же: релиз с статическим использованием Runtime lib. Все параметры настройки решения такие же. Но когда запускаю скомпилированный exe - ОС сначала требует `vcruntime140.dll` (обсуждение здесь [Как скоприлировать проект, чтобы у пользователя не требовало VCRUNTIME140.dll?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/844473/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-vcruntime140-dll/844502?noredirect=1#comment1356350_844502)). Так и не поняла почему статически не линкуются библиотеки, поэтому решила добавить `vcruntime140.dll` в тестовую систему. Теперь ОС требует `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`. Не нашла для чего нужна эта библиотека, но поняла, что это доволи редкая ошибка и есть подозрение, что она нужна для Visual Studio, а не для ОС. Просто при запросе "download api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll" как бы все первые ссылки ведут на обсуждение ошибки, а не на скачивание библиотеки. То есть я думаю, что `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` нужна для отладки, хотя компилирую для релиза. Правильно ли я понимаю свою проблему? Как её решить?

Comment: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll - это такая библиотека, которая делает прослойку между Вашим приложением и системными библиотеками. Мне не удалось от нее избавится и я их просто докопировал. Но можно попробовать другой си компилятор.

Comment: Зависимость от `vcruntime140.dll` говорит о том, что вы используете динамическую линковку рантайм библиотек, а не статическую. Проверяйте свои настройки.

Comment: @VTT У меня в `Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library` уже стоит значение `Multi-threaded (/MT)`. Делаю полную перекомпаляцию проекта. Или этого недостаточно?

Comment: Этого должно быть достаточно. Проверьте, что такая настройка стоит во всех конфигурациях. Проверьте, какой именно бинарик тянет .dll и проверьте его настройки.

Comment: @VTT "во всех конфигурациях" - это где? Помимо `Project Properties` есть ещё какие-то найстройки, где устанавливается тип линковки Runtime lib? Как проверить "какой бинарик тянет .dll"? Компилятор ведь создаёт один исполняемый файл, который я и пытаюсь запустить. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Вот в окошке Project Properties наверху два выпадающих списка - Configuration и Platform. Соответственно настройки применяются только к выбранному варианту. Собирается отдельный бинарик для каждой комбинации. Проверить зависимости можно посредством dependency walker / explorer suite / dumpbin или подобных инструментов. Например `dumpbin /IMPORTS my.dll`

Comment: @J.Huxley Чего именно вы пытаетесь добиться? Статическая компоновка для EXE, зависящего от многих DLL - чрезвычайно плохая идея. Вариант распространения всех частей CRT (как vcruntime, так и ucrt) вместе с программой вы не рассматривали? Почитайте данную статью: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/

Comment: @VTT изменила параметры конфигурации отладки, перекомпилировала - теперь не запрашивает `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`. Только `vcruntime140.dll`. Приложение запускается и работает без ошибок. Осталось разобраться почему статически не линкуется  `vcruntime140.dll`. Не знаю каким образом конфиги отладки влияют на релиз, но спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: Тут нашел простое решение it-men.su/windows-error/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

Answer (score 1):

Universal CRT с некоторого времени является компонентом Windows, поэтому статическая ее компоновка потеряла смысл. Целевые машины должны установить [соответствующее обновление](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) Windows, тогда все будет работать.

В качестве альтернативы, можно перейти на VS 2013 (последняя версия, которая не зависит от нее), или изменить в настройках проекта Platform Toolset так, чтобы он соответствовал Windows XP.

Comment: Изменила Platform Toolset. Теперь компилятор ругается, что не может найти `windows.h`, `stdlib.h` и `SDKDDKVer.h`.

Comment: @J.Huxley Это значит, что у вас не установлен выбранный тулсет… Проверяйте свои настройки. И нет никакого смысла переходить на тулсет windows XP, если нет необходимости поддерживать эту самую Windows XP.

Comment: @J.Huxley Какие Platform Toolset у вас вообще есть? Не обязательно использовать именно XP, подойдет любой, у которого целевая версия SDK не Windows 10